# Trouble with executing "While" loop, using system tray on Python

Tags: python, pyside2, system-tray

I'm trying to create application which runs block of code every X seconds, which has system tray icon with only "Quit" option. But the problem is that when it get to the tray function, it doesn't read next lines of code, and as a result, "While" loop can't be launched.
Is there any other approach to do that?

```
import time
import os
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui

class SystemTrayIcon(QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
        self.setToolTip(f'Wallpy')
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(parent)

        exit_ = menu.addAction("Exit")
        exit_.triggered.connect(lambda: sys.exit())

        menu.addSeparator()
        self.setContextMenu(menu)


def tray():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    tray_icon = SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon("tray.ico"), w)
    tray_icon.show()
    app.exec_()


def loop_function():
    print("Nice") # anything executable


tray() # launch tray icon


while True:
    loop_function() # executing every minute
    time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because, when you used the `tray()`, your main application started and the GUI main loop is initiated. It runs till your application exits, after which the `while loop` is executed.

However, if you want the loop to run simultaneously, you should integrate it with `Qt`'s main loop. In `Gtk` we do this using `GLib.add_main_thread` and other methods, I don't know about `Qt`, but you can use this general solution using Threading.

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import os
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui


def loop_function():
    print("Nice") # anything executable

def thread_loop():
    while True:
        loop_function() # executing every minute
        time.sleep(60)

class SystemTrayIcon(QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
        self.setToolTip(f'Wallpy')
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(parent)

        exit_ = menu.addAction("Exit")
        exit_.triggered.connect(lambda: sys.exit())

        menu.addSeparator()
        self.setContextMenu(menu)


def tray():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    tray_icon = SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon("tray.ico"), w)
    tray_icon.show()
    app.exec_()

my_loop = Thread(target=thread_loop, args=()) # Start the thread with no args
my_loop.start()
tray() # launch tray icon
```

Comment: there's an issue, when I click "Exit", it stucks till I close CMD window, any resolve to this?

Comment: Maybe its, because, you are connecting the "Exit" button with `sys.exit`. It is not good. Python closes your script, but the window is still there on the screen, without any controller. So the solution is to use the  proper main loop quitting in Qt.

Comment: I'll try to find proper main loop quitting, hope this works, thanks.
It will be nice if u can point me where to search it

Comment: It is a basic info. You can find it, in almost all tutorial and demo code. I have not used Qt, so let me also search. You can accept my answer, if you wish

Comment: Okay, so from Qt scripts, they are using `sys,exit(app.exec_())`, I don't know why. You can read it here https://github.com/shuage/Qt-Python-Binding-Examples

Comment: Hello, any way to apply this to my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62010865/tray-icon-script-that-uses-a-while-true-loop-cant-be-closed

Comment: @DanielBeilin sorry I don't know about the modules used in your code. The idea I suggested here is to run the blocking code (that is while loop) in a separate thread. You can copy the same logic (i.e. `thread_loop` function)  and see if it works.

Comment: @JArunMani Thanks, I tried to apply the same code but it didn't work and I might have used it wrong.