# Tray icon script that uses a while True loop can't be closed

Tags: python

I want to write a script that runs in the background and is minimized to the tray icon as long as the user doesn't exit the program. I don't have and don't need a fancy GUI, so I'm only using `infi systray` for this.

I need the script to sleep for a period of time, but I need to be able to close it by right clicking on the tray icon. When the script runs, I'm not able to do that because of the `While True` statement.

```py
from infi.systray import SysTrayIcon
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import time

starttime = time.time()
toaster = ToastNotifier()

def startTimer(systray):
    while True:
        toaster.show_toast("test1", "test1", duration=5)
        toaster.show_toast("test2", "test2", duration=5)
        time.sleep(60 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))

menu_options = (("Start", None, startTimer),)
systray = SysTrayIcon("icon.ico", "test", menu_options)
systray.start()
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not very familiar with infi systray, but it looks like your `startTimer` function is only called after you click the test option. Do you need the while loop? Or maybe I'm not understanding something...

Comment: @xdhmoore Yes, I want to click on it once to activate it. Once it's activated, the while loop runs and I'm not able to close it from the menu, only by force closing the script.